# Navigation Architecture Component - Login Button - createNavigateOnClickListener

Tags: android, android-fragments, butterknife, android-architecture-navigation

I'm using butterknife and fragments. I can't switch to other page in login controls.

```
 @OnClick(R.id.btnLogin)
    public void onBtnLoginClicked() {
       ...
       if (AndroidUtils.isInternetAvailable(context)) {
          ...
          Navigation.createNavigateOnClickListener(R.id.action_LoginF_to_MainF, null);
       }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem.

```
Navigation.findNavController(getActivity(), R.id.my_main_host_fragment).navigate(R.id.action_LoginF_to_MainF);
```